# How to create a screen like when delete a photo on photo library it displays a splash screen with 2 options: Delete Photo or Cancel?

Tags: xcode, photo, splash-screen

How to create a screen like when delete a photo on photo library it displays a splash screen with 2 options: Delete Photo or Cancel?

I don't know what component to do that. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That's called a `UIActionSheet`. It's used very much like a `UIAlertView`.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm finding. Thanks NJones so much.